# How to disable TCP SACK for CentOS?

Tags: linux, security, centos

A new security vulnerability has been announced called "TCP SACK PANIC". https://access.redhat.com/security/vulnerabilities/tcpsack

> Three related flaws were found in the Linux kernel’s handling of TCP networking.  The most severe vulnerability could allow a remote attacker to trigger a kernel panic in systems running the affected software and, as a result, impact the system’s availability.

A work around suggested by theregister.co.uk is to disable TCP SACK.

https://www.theregister.co.uk/2019/06/17/linux_tcp_sack_kernel_crash/

> Patches and mitigations are available, and can be applied by hand if needed, or you can wait for a security fix to be pushed or offered to your at-risk device. A key workaround is to set /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_sack to 0.

How do you do this on CentOS 7.6.1810?

I've tried using `sudo nano` and editing the file to 0, but I don't have permission, I tried changing the permissions to get write access and that also returned `changing permissions of 'tcp_sack': Operation not permitted`.

Comment: I realise that this may be better suited to serverfault.com

Comment: SELinux? Shared kernel virtualization?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to do

```
echo "0" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_sack
```

Make sure to do this as a **superuser**, regular system users do not have permission to alter this value.

---

This change is not parmanent by the way, add the following to your /etc/sysctl.conf to apply it on boot and you can use *sysctl -p* to directly apply the changes:

```
echo "net.ipv4.tcp_sack = 0" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
sysctl -p
```

Comment: I set `sudo su` first, and then tried both but still getting `sysctl: permission denied on key 'net.ipv4.tcp_sack'`

Comment: @user2924019 If you're root it will work. Permission denied is to be expected if you do sudo with a redirect.

Comment: I tried with root with and without sudo.

Comment: The issue is that the >> happens in the user's shell, not the sudo shell.  Do something like `sudo bash` then do the echo.

Comment: Is a reboot required?

Comment: A reboot is not required for both solutions provided, given that if you use the sysctl.conf open you run "sysctl -p" after modifying the file